# What's the best route to get your own software into Debian and Fedora?

Tags: debian, packaging, fedora

Say I am able to follow the packaging guides and have figured out how to make a working .deb and .rpm, how can I get distros to actually include my software?

What's firstly the quickest / easiest way, and secondly the most appropriate / official way?

What if my software depends on other people's libraries that do not have packages?  Do I then get the responsibility of packaging those?

Comment: This is basically what I was looking for: http://mentors.debian.net/cgi-bin/maintainer-intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points based on my experience with [Debian](http://www.debian.org):

- these are volunteer-driven distros, so making the life of others easier is always a good thing so make sure your software builds cleanly, is documented well etc pp
- pre-requisites matter: if your software has Depends: and hence Build-Depends: on other software, then you have to provide that software first
- you can always start with local repositories, and/or .deb and .rpm files hosted on your sourceforge / Google Code / ... site
- if your software is good and relevant, chances are someone will include it, especially if you start to build a bit of a community
- if everything else fails, scratch your own itch and apply to become a Debian Maintainer (DM) so that your packaging can go into the archive

The devel is always in the details.  I happen to be a Debian Developer and maintain some software for which I am the upstream author, but I also have other projects that I have not yet put into Debian and may not for some time as they are more specialised.

Comment: Thanks.  But why should even "specialised" software not make it into Debian?  When doing specialised work, it's great to find that software is already available.

Anyways from what I take from your answer, becoming a DM is the best way to get my own software in there if I'm not expecting a sudden huge crowd of followers.  This means applying and getting a sponsor and all that, which seems like an exasperating amount of work just to upload a file.  But maybe worth the trouble.

Isn't there a place one can just place source debs for review by someone who might then upload it?

Comment: Yes, try the debian-mentors list. But recall, you have to convince someone to spend his/her time on your project.  Just "because you build it" it doesn't mean that "they will come".

Comment: I guess I have to admit that find it somewhat difficult that one has to do so much "convincing" just to distribute your own software in a convenient way.  Anyways, thanks, I'll probably follow up and learn more about the process.